# sending mail by System.Net.Mail

Tags: asp.net, email

I am just born baby in ASP.Net basket. I am reading Wrox Beginners for ASP.NET 4.0 and there was reading about sending mails using System.Net.Mail.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();  // Getting Error
    myMessage.Subject = "Test Message";
    myMessage.Body = "Hello World, from Planet Wrox";
    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("sendID@net.com", "Barack Obama");
    myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("recieveID@net.com", "George Bush"));
    SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
}
```

I wrote this code in pages load event. But I am getting error in first line as

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The specified string is not in the
>   form required for an e-mail address. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: The specified string is not
>   in the form required for an e-mail address.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 11:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 12:     { 
Line 13:         MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
Line 14:         myMessage.Subject = "Test Message"; 
Line 15:         myMessage.Body = "Hello World, from Planet Wrox";
```

Can any one tell whats the problem?

Comment: Shame on me for promoting this kind of behavior, but +1 for the phrase "I am just born baby in ASP.Net basket." Just too funny!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a class that includes everything you need:

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper class for the System.Net.Mail objects
/// </summary>
public class SmtpMailMessage : IDisposable
{
    #region declarations

    MailMessage Message;
    SmtpClient SmtpMailClient;

    #endregion

    #region constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor for the SmtpMailMessage class
    /// </summary>
    public SmtpMailMessage()
    {
        //initialize the mail message
        Message = new MailMessage();
        Message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
        Message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;            
        Message.From = new MailAddress("abc@abc.com");           

        //initialize the smtp client
        SmtpMailClient = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpMailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        SmtpMailClient.Host = "192.168.0.1";
        SmtpMailClient.Port = 25;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parameterized constructor for the SmtpMailMessage class. Allows for override of the default
    /// SMTP host and port number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="HostIP">The IP address of the exchange server</param>
    /// <param name="PortNumber">The port number for ingoing and outgoing SMTP messages</param>
    public SmtpMailMessage(string HostIP, int PortNumber) : this()
    {
        //override the smtp host value
        SmtpMailClient.Host = HostIP;

        //override the smtp port value
        SmtpMailClient.Port = PortNumber;
    }

    #endregion

    #region subject / body

    /// <summary>
    /// The body content of the mail message
    /// </summary>
    public string Body
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.Body;
        }
        set
        {
            Message.Body = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the subject of the mail message
    /// </summary>
    public string Subject
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.Subject;
        }
        set
        {
            Message.Subject = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region mail type

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that determines whether the mail message
    /// should be formatted as HTML or text
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsHtmlMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.IsBodyHtml;
        }
        set
        {
            Message.IsBodyHtml = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region sender

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the from address of this message
    /// </summary>
    public string From
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.From.Address;
        }
        set
        {
            Message.From = new MailAddress(value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region recipients

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the collection of recipients
    /// </summary>
    public MailAddressCollection To
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.To;                
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the collection of CC recipients 
    /// </summary>
    public MailAddressCollection CC
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.CC;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the collection of Bcc recipients
    /// </summary>
    public MailAddressCollection Bcc
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.Bcc;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region delivery notification

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the delivery notification settings for this message
    /// </summary>
    public DeliveryNotificationOptions DeliveryNotifications
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.DeliveryNotificationOptions;
        }
        set
        {
            Message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region priority

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Priority of this message
    /// </summary>
    public MailPriority PriorityLevel
    {
        get
        {
            return Message.Priority;
        }
        set
        {
            Message.Priority = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region send methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the message anonymously (without credentials)
    /// </summary>
    public void Send()
    {
        SmtpMailClient.Send(Message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the message with authorization from a network account   
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Username">The Windows username of the authorizing user</param>
    /// <param name="Password">The Windows password of the authorizing user</param>
    /// <param name="Domain">The domain name of the network to which the authorizing user belongs</param>
    public void Send(string Username, string Password, string Domain)
    {
        //attach a network credential to this message using the information passed into the method
        SmtpMailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, Domain);

        //send the message
        SmtpMailClient.Send(Message);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable implementation

    ~SmtpMailMessage()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);            
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (Message != null)
                Message.Dispose();
            Message = null;                
            SmtpMailClient = null;
        }
    }

    #endregion        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in order for you to use the MailMessage() with an empty constructor, you need to have the "From" value set in the SmtpSettings in your configuration file.  From here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144707.aspx

> Remarks
>
> ---
>
> From is set to the value in the network element for
>   mailSettings Element (Network Settings), if it exists.

An easier solution might be to use the constructor that takes a From address and To address.

from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14k9fb7t.aspx

```
string to = "jane@contoso.com";
string from = "ben@contoso.com";
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your smtp settings are correct in the web.config file.